# Setting 'connection-properties-prefix' in spring servlet context using property-placeholder

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-mvc, servlets

I have the following in my dispatch-servlet.xml file ...

```
...


<context:property-placeholder/>

<orcl:pooling-datasource id="dataSource" properties-location="resources/db/orcl.properties"
   connection-properties-prefix="${optout.env}" />

...
```

When the servlet loads I see the following error:

> SEVERE: Servlet /optout threw load() exception
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:   Configuration problem: pooling-datasource defined without the required 'url' attribute and the property file does not contain a "url" entry
>   Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatch-servlet.xml]

After some debugging the "PoolingDataSourceBeanDefinitionParser" reads `${optout.env}` from the element node as the string, no property replacement is taking place

Why is spring not replacing the `${...}` in my config file?

Comment: Probably because it hasn't loaded it yet (you are after all using it in the same tag as the property file)

Comment: Sorry, .. The ${optout.env} is set on the JVM using -Doptout.env=test, ... it should be loaded.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the JVM argument is being passed to the code?

Comment: yes. I am setting another property the same way. & it is available to the app at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

So after a long dev cycle on this I have found a solution, ...

The following will work.

In the dispact-servlet.xml file:

```
...

<orcl:pooling-datasource id="dataSource" 
    url="${${optout.env}.url}" 
    username="${${optout.env}.user}" 
    password="${${optout.env}.password}" />

<context:property-placeholder location="resources/db/orcl.properties"/>

...
```

Spring now resolves the ${optout.env} placeholder correctly subsituting 'test.url', 'test.user', 'test.password' respectively, ...